# Automake: How to prefix a command to compiler command

Tags: makefile, prefix, automake, scorep

The following quote is taken from documentation of [scorep](https://silc.zih.tu-dresden.de/scorep-current/pdf/scorep.pdf). In order to use the software, the `scorep` command is said to prefixed to compiler which is `mpicc`. I am using automake. So far, in `configure.ac` I had `AC_PROG_CC([mpicc])`. How can I prefix the `scorep` command to compiler command with automake?

> When makefiles are employed to build the application, it is convenient
>   to define a placeholder variable to indicate whether a “preparation''
>   step like an instrumentation is desired or only the pure compilation
>   and linking. For example, if this variable is called PREP then the
>   lines defining the C compiler in the makefile can be changed from:
>
> `MPICC = mpicc` to `MPICC = $(PREP) mpicc`
>
> One can then use the same makefile to either build an instru- mented
>   version with the
>
> `make PREP="scorep"`
>
> command or a fully optimized and not instrumented default build by
>   simply using:
>
> `make`.

Answer (score 0):

If your package must always be built with `scorep`, then just prepend it to `CC` in your `configure.ac`, like:

```
AC_PROG_CC([mpicc])
CC="scorep $CC"
```

This will cause a build failure if the user building your package doesn't have `scorep`, but presumably that's what you want.  (Or you could add a check to `configure.ac` to have it error if `scorep` is not found.)

If you want the user to optionally use `scorep`, you could make the above assignment conditional.  One common way is to use an option, in your case, say, `--with-scorep`.

A final option is to do nothing and let users wanting this functionality request it like:

```
make CC='scorep mpicc'
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to Score-P.

I would like to share Score-P mailing list's answer. Based on this [link](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/kb_articles/software-scorep/), it is necessary to configure with

```
SCOREP_WRAPPER=OFF ../configure \
     CC=scorep-mpicc \
     CXX=scorep-mpicxx \
     FC=scorep-mpif90 \
     --disable-dependency-tracking
```

Answer (score 0):

[Install_Scorep](https://github.com/iamjosephvarghese/Install_Scorep) is a bash script to install Score-P 3.0 on Linux based systems. To install Score-P clone the repository and run the script named install_scorep.sh. This will do all the necessary tasks to successfully install Score-P 3.0 .